# Compile more than one C file into a single non executable object file

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, linker

I have 2 files:

> A.c

and

> B.c

Both of them don't have a main function.
How can I compile and link them into one single non executable file named D.o ?

Comment: You can always include another c file using `#include`

Comment: Create a third c source file which includes both and compile the third. May be better than @0x90? Or create a lib.

Comment: @0x90 No, quite often you can't (e.g. if both files use same name for local static variable but there are also other cases).

Comment: Always is a negotiable term :)

Comment: Your title is better than the title of the duplicate, but you're asking for the same thing and the correct answer is essentially the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first compile them to separate object files and then link those with preserved relocatable info via `ld -r`:

```
ld -r tmp1.o tmp2.o -o tmp.o
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a non-executable file, @yugr solution is just fine. However, if it's not necessary at all, here is how to link multiple files and create a single object file.

*GCC:*
`gcc -o d.o a.c b.c`

Note that `-o` is used to specify a name for the object file.

However, if you want to do things better, you should take a look at [makefile](https://sites.google.com/site/michaelsafyan/software-engineering/how-to-write-a-makefile), and create an object file for each source file, then compile them together.

Little example:

```
exe:    a.o b.o
        gcc -o exe a.o b.o

a.o:    a.c
        gcc -c a.c

b.o:    b.c
        gcc -c b.c
```

Comment: How is this relevant? The OP explicitly asked for non executable output.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see it.